# Xamarin ImageSource.FromStream(Func<Stream>) why is the parameter not just Stream but Func<Stream>?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, stream

I think the title sums it up. I'm trying to set the source of an image in Xamarin using a stream but the method asks for a `Func<Stream>` as a parameter. I could just wrap the stream with a method but I don't really know if this could cause future problems. In conclusion, I want to set the source of an image in Xamarin using a stream and I neither know or could find, how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This approach is usually used for some Lazy-Loading purposes.
That means, the `Stream` is not accessed in the moment of passing it to the function.
Instead the function for getting/creating the `Stream` is saved and is used when is needed.

For example for image it could be when the image should appear on the screen (to prevent consumption of resources when the image is not visible).

So it's better to create the function that will create new `Stream` rather than keeping the opened stream in memory.

Example:

```
ImageSource.FromStream(() => File.OpenRead(path));
```